# how to summarize grouped data with different functions that return different numbers of return values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am work on a grouped dataset and I want to add 4 summarizing statistics as 4 new columns: count, mean, ci lower, ci upper.

I summarized mean, ci lower, ci upper as following:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)

# summarize count, mean, confidence intervals and make four new columns;
mtcars %>% group_by(vs, am) %>%
    do(
        as.data.frame(as.list(smean.cl.normal(.$mpg)))
    )
#      vs    am     Mean    Lower    Upper
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     0     0 15.05000 13.28723 16.81277
# 2     0     1 19.75000 15.54295 23.95705
# 3     1     0 20.74286 18.45750 23.02822
# 4     1     1 28.37143 23.97129 32.77157
```

however, when I add count, the new columns becomes 2 columns of lists:

```
df <- mtcars %>% group_by(vs, am) %>%
    do(
        n = length(.$mpg),
        stats = smean.cl.normal(.$mpg)
    )

# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#      vs    am         n     stats
# * <dbl> <dbl>    <list>    <list>
# 1     0     0 <int [1]> <dbl [3]>
# 2     0     1 <int [1]> <dbl [3]>
# 3     1     0 <int [1]> <dbl [3]>
# 4     1     1 <int [1]> <dbl [3]>
```

my desired output is:

```
#      vs    am     n     Mean    Lower    Upper
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     0     0    12 15.05000 13.28723 16.81277
# 2     0     1     6 19.75000 15.54295 23.95705
# 3     1     0     7 20.74286 18.45750 23.02822
# 4     1     1     7 28.37143 23.97129 32.77157
```

How should I achieve this conveniently?

Thanks in advance.

---

I also tried:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(vs, am) %>%
    do(
        as.data.frame(as.list(c(length(.$mpg), smean.cl.normal(.$mpg))))
    )

# Source: local data frame [4 x 8]
# Groups: vs, am [4]
# 
# vs    am   X12     Mean    Lower    Upper    X6    X7
# <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0     0    12 15.05000 13.28723 16.81277    NA    NA
# 2     0     1    NA 19.75000 15.54295 23.95705     6    NA
# 3     1     0    NA 20.74286 18.45750 23.02822    NA     7
# 4     1     1    NA 28.37143 23.97129 32.77157    NA     7
```

This gives strange results.

Comment: So why in your second attempt you didn't wrap it up into `data.frame`? Why did you assume it should just suddenly work without it? I think you could simply add it with `c` using something like `mtcars %>% group_by(vs, am) %>% do(as.data.frame(as.list(c(n = length(.$mpg), smean.cl.normal(.$mpg)))))`, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I did try a similar way: `mtcars %>% group_by(vs, am) %>%
    do(
        as.data.frame(as.list(c(length(.$mpg), smean.cl.normal(.$mpg))))
    )`. This gives strange columns with `NA`s. So I think this wouldn't work.  Why I get strange results without `n=`?

Comment: Because dplyr is trying to be smart and assigns it a new name by doing something like `paste0("X", length(.$mpg))` for each group, and hence, `data.frame` adds a new column each time with the new name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this without `do` using multiple `tidyverse` packages, namely `tidyr`, `dplyr`, `purrr` and `broom`.

The reason behind this is that [`do` will eventually be replaced by `purrr`](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/719542847045636096)

It does:

1. group by vs and am
2. nest mpg into a list-frame.
3. create the stats column and n column as a list-frame.
4. unnest the list frames into separate rows and columns.
5. drop the data list frame.

You do need to do some finagling to get the `smean.cl.normal` in the proper form in step 3.  My approach was transform the output into a tidy data frame with `broom::tidy` then `tidyr::spread` the rows into columns. The its in the proper tidy form for each vs/am group.  This approach can probably be improved and hope those suggestions would be posted in comments.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs, am) %>% 
  nest(mpg) %>% 
  mutate(stats = map(data, ~spread(tidy(smean.cl.normal(.x$mpg)), names, x)),
         n = map(data, nrow)) %>% 
  unnest(stats, n) %>% 
  select(-data)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the updated tidyverse way. why `df <- mtcars %>% group_by(vs, am) %>%
    do(
        n = length(.$mpg),
        stats = smean.cl.normal(.$mpg)
    ) %>% unnest(stats, n)` doesn't work? Is a nested column (which looks like a column of list) different from a column of list for `unnest`?

Comment: You'd have unnest each separately, then summarize with the do method due to row number differences.